# Notice: Use of undefined constant GLOB_BRACE

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu-16.04, opencart2.x

Getting Notice and Warning Bellow

> Notice: Use of undefined constant GLOB_BRACE - assumed 'GLOB_BRACE' in /var/www/html/opencart/upload/admin/controller/extension/extension.php on line 2
>
> Warning: glob(): At least one of the passed flags is invalid or not supported on this platform in /var/www/html/opencart/upload/admin/controller/extension/extension.php on line 41
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/opencart/upload/admin/controller/extension/extension.php on line 44

When i list all defined constant `GLOB_BRACE` is missing.

```
GLOB_MARK => 2
GLOB_NOSORT => 4
GLOB_NOCHECK => 16
GLOB_NOESCAPE => 64
GLOB_ERR => 1
GLOB_ONLYDIR => 1073741824
GLOB_AVAILABLE_FLAGS => 1073741911
```

Operating System,php, Opencart Version:

- Linux opencart-77fcc87595-2gqvw 4.4.86+ #1 SMP Thu Dec 7 20:11:11 PST 2017 x86_64
- Linux
- Current PHP version: 7.1.12
- OpenCart Version 2.3.0.2

I have all ready read the documentation [`array glob ( string $pattern \[, int $flags = 0 \] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

I am 100% sure it is not issue of OpenCart

Comment: It may be a OS issue only. See this thread https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stdlib/issues/58

Comment: And another link: https://github.com/CachetHQ/Cachet/issues/2586

Comment: [TFM](http://php.net/glob): *Note: The `GLOB_BRACE` flag is not available on some non GNU systems, like Solaris.*

Comment: If the constant is not defined, then it is obviously not supported by your PHP build, regardless of whether the operating system should normally support it. I couldn't say why that would be the case, given that you state that you're running a Linux platform, but it is the case. Possibly you have a custom-built PHP, or your system is missing the necessary libraries, or something like that; I can't really help on the how it happened or how to fix it, but it does seem pretty clear that it's not available on your system.

Answer (score 6):

Since this happened to me as a former happy `glob` user:

As mentioned in the comments above - `GLOB_BRACE` is not available in some Operating Systems. For example the popular Alpine Linux -  which is heavily used in Docker containers. Alpine Linux uses musl libc instead of GNU libc.

The fix is: Do not use `GLOB_BRACE` when you want to run your code on for example Alpine Linux.

When you are using the mentioned "OpenCart": There is some movement in form of a [PR](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/pull/7614).